# How to extract only few columns from Nifi Flow File after reading the data from a flat file

Tags: apache-nifi

The flat file has the following data without a header which needs to be loaded into the MySQL table.

```
101,AAA,1000,10
102,BBB,5000,20
```

I use GetFile or GetSFTP processor to read the data. Once the data is read, the flow file contains the above data. I want to only load the 1st column, 2nd column, and 4th column into the MySQL table. The output I expect in MySQL table is as below.

```
101,AAA,10
102,BBB,20
```

Can you please help me with how to extract only a few columns from an incoming flow file in nifi and load it into MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

This is just one way to do it, but there are several other ways. This method uses Records, and otherwise avoids modifying the underlying data - it simply ignores the fields you don't want during the `insert`. This is beneficial when integrating with a larger Flow, where the data is used by other Processors that might expect the original data, or where you are already using Records.

Let's say your Table has the columns

```
id | name | value
```

and your data looks like

```
101,AAA,1000,10
102,BBB,5000,20
```

You could use a `PutDatabaseRecord` processor with `Unmatched Field Behavior` and `Unmatched Column Behavior` set to `Ignore Unmatched...` and add a `CSVReader` as the `Record Reader`.

In the `CSVReader` you could set the `Schema Access Strategy` to `Use 'Schema Text' Property`. Then set the `Schema Text` property to the following:

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "nifi",
     "name": "db",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "id", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "name", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "ignoredField", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "value", "type": "string" }
     ]
}
```

This would match the NiFi Record fields against the DB Table columns, which would match fields 1,2 and 4 while ignoring fields 3 (as it did not match a column name).

Obviously, amend the field names in the `Schema Text` schema to match the Column names of your DB Table. You can also do data types checking/conversion here.

[PutDatabaseRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/)

[CSVReader](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.csv.CSVReader/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another method could be to use convert your flowfile to a record, with the help of [ConvertRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord/index.html).
It helps transforming to an CSV format to whatever you prefer, you can still keep CSV format.

But with your flowfile beeing a record you can now use additionnal processors like:
[QueryRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html), so you can run SQL like command on the flow file:

> "SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE"

and in your case, you can do :

> "SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM FLOWFILE"

you can also directly apply filtering :

> "SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM FLOWFILE WHERE col1>500"

I recommand you the following reading:

- [Query Record tutorial](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Running-SQL-on-FlowFiles-using-QueryRecord-Processor-Apache/ta-p/246671)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much pdeuxa and Sdairs for your reply. your inputs were helpful. I have tried to use a similar method as both of you did. I used `convertRecord` and configured `CSVRecordReader` and `CSVSetRecordWriter`. `CSVRecordReader` has the following schema to read the data

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "nifi",
     "name": "db",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "id", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "name", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "Salary", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "dept", "type": "string" }
     ]
}
```

while the `CSVSetRecordWriter` has the following output schema. There are 4 fields in Input schema while the output Schema only has 3 columns.

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "nifi",
     "name": "db",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "id", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "name", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "dept", "type": "string" }
     ]
}
```

I was able to successfully run this. Thanks for your input guys.